# MS Exchange and Outlook - how to find all outgoing mail for an account.NOT setup in outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

Is there a way for me to find all the emails sent out using our outgoing mail server for an account NOT setup in outlook client?

We are a museum, and In our facility we have an interactive exhibit that can take a photo of a person (via webcam) and send the photo to them via email. I know the exhibit was set up using our mail server (outgoing) and at one time we provided the vendor our mail server settings and an email address to  use. The email address i can see in our Exchange Management Console (Recipient Configuration \ mailbox) as a user mailbox.  I can also see the user in Active Directory listed in domain\users\  as of type user.   Our marketing department is now interested in all of the email addresses our server sent the webcam photos too. When I try load the user in Outlook client to see if I can see anything in the SENT mailbox, I see nothing.  When I try to use the EMC message tracking feature, I am brought to the web page  (manage my organization) where i have access to mail control feature such as delivery reports. However, when i select the mailbox to search and then check "Search for message sent to:"   I also get nothing .

Any help would be greatly appreciative

Answer (score 0):

Could the recipients receive photos from the facility? You could do test that sending the photo to your own mailbox.
As you mentioned, it is a user mailbox. Please contact your vendor how did they create it for the device and realize sending messages feature?

In general, we could configure SMTP-enabled appliances (e.g. printers/scanners/webcam) to send messages via Exchange External SMTP relay, the ability to make an SMTP connection to an Exchange server and send email to recipients that are outside the organization. With this method, the device doesn't have a mailbox, neither has items in the sent items folder. More details please see the link below:

**How to Configure a Relay Connector in Exchange Server 2013( The method also applies in Exchange 2010)**

https://practical365.com/exchange-server/exchange-2013-configure-smtp-relay-connector/

Comment: Yes, the recipients receive the email with the attached photos.  That is not the issue. We know the system works. All recipients receive the emails.  We just want to be able to capture the email addresses. That is go in at the end of the season and look at all the mail sent.  Hwoever, I see no record of it anywhere. Like I said, the only difference is that the email account/user  account is not installed in an outlook client. I can go log onto any machine in our organization and run outlook and pull my email over.

Comment: If you log on OWA, could you see the items in the folder?